# How can I clean a TSV file having record or fields separators in one of its fields?

Tags: csv

Given a TSV file with col2 that contains either a field or record separator (FS/RS) being respectively a tab or a carriage return which are escaped/surrounded by quotes.

```
$ printf '%b\n' 'col1\tcol2\tcol3' '1\t"A\tB"\t1234' '2\t"CD\nEF"\t567' | \cat -vet
col1^Icol2^Icol3$
1^I"A^IB"^I1234$
2^I"CD$
EF"^I567$

+------+---------+------+
| col1 | col2    | col3 |
+------+---------+------+
| 1    | "A   B" | 1234 |
| 2    | "CD     | 567  |
|      | EF"     |      |
+------+---------+------+
```

Is there a way in sed/awk/perl or even (preferably) miller/mlr to transform those pesky characters into spaces in order to generate the following result:

```
+------+---------+------+
| col1 | col2    | col3 |
+------+---------+------+
| 1    | "A B"   | 1234 |
| 2    | "CD EF" | 567  |
+------+---------+------+
```

I cannot get miller 6.2 to make the proper transformation (tried with DSL put/gsub) because it doesn't recognize the tab or CR/LF being part of the columns which breaks the field number:

```
$ printf '%b\n' 'col1\tcol2\tcol3' '1\t"A\tB"\t1234' '2\t"CD\nEF"\t567' | mlr --opprint --barred --itsv cat
mlr :  mlr: CSV header/data length mismatch 3 != 4 at filename (stdin) line  2.
```

Comment: when you said "carriage return" you meant just \r , or \r\n, or \n ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you run

```
printf '%b\n' 'col1\tcol2\tcol3' '1\t"A\tB"\t1234' '2\t"CD\nEF"\t567' | \
mlr --c2t --fs "\t" clean-whitespace
```

```
col1    col2    col3
1       A B     1234
2       CD EF   567
```

I'm using mlr 6.2.

A way to do it in miller 5 is to use simply the put verb:

```
printf '%b\n' 'col1\tcol2\tcol3' '1\t"A\tB"\t1234' '2\t"CD\nEF"\t567' | \
mlr --tsv  put -S 'for (k in $*) {$[k] = gsub($[k], "\n", " ")}' then clean-whitespace
```

Comment: Thanks, this works very well, but I'm wondering why mlr cannot handle the file in it's native form and one has to use the CSV format with the TSV separator in order to parse the fields correctly

Comment: @CyrilChaboisseau  I do not why. A tsv is a csv that uses tab as separator and for csv there is a strong rfc4180 check.

Comment: FWIW, this command fails with miller 5.6.2 in ubuntu 20.04 (it replaces runs with the first whitespace character found (so `"a \tb"` becomes `a b` but `"a\ta"` is unchanged, for example)

Comment: @jhnc I have edited my reply and I have added a miller 5 way to do it

Comment: @CyrilChaboisseau I have opened a new issue about your question https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/issues/1035#issue-1262768368

Comment: @aborruso maybe `[[:space:]]+` instead of `\n` then you could skip the clean-whitespace

Answer (score 3):

A good library cleanly handles things like embedded newlines and quoted separators (in fields)

In a Perl script with [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/release/ISHIGAKI/Text-CSV-1.95/view/lib/Text/CSV.pm)

```perl
use warnings; 
use strict;

use Text::CSV;

my $file = shift // die "Usage: $0 filename\n";

my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { binary => 1, sep_char => "\t", auto_diag => 1 } ); 

open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!"; 

while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) { 
    s/\s+/ /g for @$row;      # collapse multiple spaces, tabs, newlines
    $csv->say(*STDOUT, $row);
}
```

Note the many other [options for the constructor](https://metacpan.org/release/ISHIGAKI/Text-CSV-1.95/view/lib/Text/CSV.pm#new-(%5C%25attr)) that can help handle various irregularities.

This can fit in a one-liner; its functional interface (with `csv`) is particularly well suited for that.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
perl -MText::CSV_XS=csv -e'
   csv
      in       => *ARGV,
      on_in    => sub { s/\s+/ /g for @{$_[1]} },
      sep_char => "\t";
'
```

Or `s/[\t\n]/ /g` if you prefer.

Can be placed all on one line.

Input is accepted from file named by argument or STDIN.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for multi-char `RS`, `RT`, and `gensub()`:

```
$ awk -v RS='"([^"]|"")*"' '{ORS=gensub(/[\n\t]/," ","g",RT)} 1' file
col1    col2    col3
1       "A B"   1234
2       "CD EF" 567
```

The above just uses `RS` to isolate each `"..."` string and saves it in `RT`, then replaces every `\n` or `\t` in that string with a blank and saves the result in `ORS`, then prints the record.

Answer (score 0):

you absolutely don't need `gawk` to get this done - here's one that works for `mawk`, `gawk`, or `macos nawk` :

**INPUT**

```
--before--
col1    col2    col3
1   "A  B"  1234
2   "CD
EF" 567
```

**CODE**

```
{m,n,g}awk '
BEGIN {
 1      __=substr((OFS=FS="\t\"")(FS)(ORS=_)\
                      (RS = "^$"),_+=_^=_<_,_)
}
END {
 1      printbefore()
 3      for (_^=_<_; _<=NF; _++) {
 3          sub(/[\t-\r]+/, ($_~__)?" ":"&", $_)
        }
 1      print
}
 1  function printbefore(_)
{
 1      printf("\n\n--before--\n%s\n------"\
               "------AFTER------\n\n", $+_)>("/dev/stderr")
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
———AFTER  (using mawk)------
 
col1  col2    col3
1     "A B"   1234
2     "CD EF" 567
```

strip out the part about `printbefore()` that's more for debugging purposes, then it's just

```
{m,n,g}awk '

BEGIN { __=substr((OFS=FS="\t\"") FS \
                  (ORS=_)        (RS="^$"),_+=_^=_<_,_) 
} END {
    for(--_;_<=NF;_++) {
        sub(/[\t-\r]+/, $_~__?" ":"&",$_) } print }'
```